# Image is Not display in email that send by Nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I am working on nopcommerce (version 3.60) message template i have put image and give also proper path to image location. Mail is sent properly but its not display image in gmail,yahoo. i have configure my mail template like below

```
<p><img src="http://example.org/Content/Images/logo (2).png" alt="" width="173" height="86" /></p>
<p><a href="%Store.URL%">%Store.Name%</a><br /> <br /> To activate your account <a href="%Customer.AccountActivationURL%">click here</a>. <br /> <br /> %Store.Name%</p>
```

Is any configuration missing please tell me. and also is gmail or yahoo denied image to be display in mail for security?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy for a hacker to replace the image `src` attribute with a Javascript file that send a request on behalf of an authenticated user to a particular site and do some damage, this is called CSRF attack, for this reason they don't show pictures in emails to protect their users, they show image if it's coming from a trusted source.

Comment: Thank you for your response. you are right its only get value if email comes from trusted source. But is any way to display image if its not coming from trusted source.

Comment: @vatsal All I can think of is to change the image to something non-threatening, something like changing the image if it's for styling to css styling, or attaching the image to email and than sending it, but I don't think it'll solve any of your problem, also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532/what-is-the-best-way-to-send-html-image-email) see if it solves your problem.